# Polar decomposition of invertible operators

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

I'm looking for references wich treat the following properties:

Let H be a hilbert space. Let $T \in B(H)$ be an invertible operator. Suppose that $T= U |T|$ is the polar decomposition of T. Then we have:

1. $T^{-1} = U^*|T^{-1} |$ is the polar decomposition of $T^{-1}$.
2. $|T^{-1}|= {|T^*|}^{-1}.$
3. ${({|T|}^{-1})}^\alpha = U^* {(|T^{-1}|)}^\alpha U$ ,  for each $\alpha >0$.

Could you please suggest me some references on this please.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most textbooks, these would be exercises at best. Mostly, you need to notice that
$$\tag1
|T^{-1}|^2=(T^{-1})^*T^{-1}=(T^*)^{-1}T^{-1}=(TT^*)^{-1}=|T^*|^{-2},
$$
which is 2.

From the fact that $T$ is invertible, it follows that $U$ is a unitary:
$$
U^*U=(T|T|^{-1})^*T|T|^{-1}=|T|^{-1}T^*T|T|^{-1}=|T|^{-1}|T|^2|T|^{-1}=I,
$$
and $U$ is surjective because $T$ is.

Now, from $T=U|T|$ we get $T^{-1}=|T|^{-1}U^*$; and then
$$
|T^{-1}|^2=(|T|^{-1}U^*)^*|T|^{-1}U^*=U|T|^{-2}U^*=(U|T|^{-1}U^*)^2,
$$
so $$\tag2|T^{-1}|=U|T|^{-1}U^*.$$ Then
$$
T^{-1}=|T|^{-1}U^*=U^*|T^{-1}|UU^*=U^*|T^{-1}|
$$
is the polar decomposition.

Finally, item 3 follows directly from $(2)$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer !